# Sessions on Memcached in Django - no items in Memcached

Tags: django, memcached, django-sessions

I'm setting up sessions in Django using memcached, and after logging in, no items appear in the cache.

I can connect to my memcached instance with `telnet localhost 11211` and `stats` says the process is running. My cache settings are as follows:

```
CACHES = {
    'default': {
        'BACKEND': 'django.core.cache.backends.memcached.PyLibMCCache',
        'LOCATION': '127.0.0.1:11211' # can also be a list of locations
    }
}
SESSION_ENGINE = 'django.contrib.sessions.backends.cached_db'
```

and I do have the database set up for the caching. The sessions show up in the database. (when using just `backends.cache` nothing shows up in the database or the cache.)

So is this the expected behavior? Do I have to store something special in the session key for it to register?

Comment: `Do I have to store something in the session key for it to register?` <-- This is easy to verify yourself.

Comment: I am storing things in the session. I meant something special, but I should have said that. Edited.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm using 1.2 and was reading the docs for 1.3.

In 1.2, the cache looks like this: `CACHE_BACKEND = "memcached://127.0.0.1:11211/"` instead of the caches dictionary.

Answer (score 0):

You also need to add two middleware classes into your MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES setting as described here:
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/cache/?from=olddocs#the-per-site-cache

MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES = (
    'django.middleware.cache.UpdateCacheMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.cache.FetchFromCacheMiddleware',
)

Answer (score 0):

Use `django.core.cache.backends.locmem.LocMemCache` as below

```
CACHES={
        "default":{
                    "BACKEND":"django.core.cache.backends.memcached.MemcachedCache",
                    "LOCATION": "127.0.0.1:11211"
                    },

        }
```